# Does laughing have any other connotation?

Tags: word-usage

Got a photo-comment (meme) from a person reading this:

> *Now I am at a stage where when someone says "I am leaving", it doesn't
>   affect me anymore but when someone says "I will always be there for
>   you", it literally makes me **laugh**.*

What is it that makes him laugh? It appears to me that the person doesn't believe this lie but why 'laugh'?

Comment: If you check a dictionary you should find a meaning of the word *laugh* that corresponds with "ridicule; scorn". It's not the same as the laughter from a comedy show and so you're right about the different connotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Making someone laugh* can mean that you tell that person something that is so ridiculous that they cannot take it seriously, so they take it as a joke (even if it is a bad one).

See for instance the expression [don't make me laugh!](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/don-t-make-me-laugh) from cambridge.org:

> said to someone to show that you cannot take ​their ​suggestion ​seriously

So *it always makes me laugh* seems to indicate that the speaker cannot take that sentence seriously anymore, it seems like a (bad) joke when someone says it.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to oerkelens' great answer, the implied circumstance is that the poster of the meme got used to being left behind, that words of assurance, "I will always be there for you", are now ridiculous. The presentiment is 'quite' funny (and somehow unbelievable based on the person's past experiences) that the words of assurance could not be taken seriously anymore, hence, it makes the person laugh.